# Letter of the Dvar Avraham About R. Soloveitchik

Tags: acharonim, rav-joseph-ber-soloveitchik

Where can the [D'var Avraham](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avraham_Duber_Kahana_Shapiro)'s letter about [R. Soloveitchik](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joseph_B._Soloveitchik)  be found? I have seen numerous references to it, such as in [R. Yitzchak Twersky's eulogy for R. Soloveichik](http://traditionarchive.org/news/originals/Volume%2030/No.%204/The%20Rov.pdf)  in which the following was quoted:

> נחה עליו רוח זקנו הארי החי הגדול שבחבורה...כמוהו מושל בים התלמוד על עמקי תהומותיו, וכל רז לא אניס ליה

---

Answer (score 2):

Woops. The source for the letter is cited by R. Twersky [there](http://traditionarchive.org/news/originals/Volume%2030/No.%204/The%20Rov.pdf): "The letter of the Kovner Rav is reprinted as the foreword to זכרון הרב.

It can be read [here](https://oukosher.org/content/uploads/2012/12/mes9.pdf) (page 5).